# how to send data to function in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a modal/dialog with two buttons, "OK" and Cancel. When I hit "OK" I want to send these data to a function on the server. How can I accomplish this? Can anyone give me some information/example? I belive I would have to use "$.post" but again, how would I send it to a particular page's function?

*UPDATED* ... still cannot reach code behind function.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({ 
                    modal: true,
                    //autoOpen: false,
                    bgiframe: false,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    width: 520,
                    height: 360,
                    open: function(event, ui) { 
                            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'position', 'center'); },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Send",
                            click: function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: 'test.aspx/GetName',
                                    data: '{name:"' + name + '}',
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    async: false
                                });
                            }
                        }],
                    draggable: false });
            return false;


<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetName(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return "Hello " & name & Environment.NewLine & "The Current Time is: " & _
             DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: I guess you want to reach the function SendEmail? You need to change url to 'test.aspx/SendEmail'.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. still cant get to "GetName" function. Is there some kind of ajax settings I would need on my page?

Comment: can you add this after async as a test: `,success : function(data) { alert( data.d ); }`

Comment: updated code example with `,success : function(data) { alert( data.d ); }`

Comment: @thomasvdb ... still nothing. I dont get any alert.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery for this. I've implemented this already a couple of times and it works like a charm.
You need to define a static WebMethod in your code-behind like this:

**C#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SayHello( string name ) { 
   // say hello
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SayHello(name As String)
   ' say hello
End Function
```

Now you can call this with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'yourPage.aspx/SayHello',
   data: "{name: '" + aValue + "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   async: false,
   success : function(data) { 
       // in case you would use a return value in your webmethod
       alert( data.d ); 
   }
});
```

As you can see you can define any page you want, it doesn't need to be your current page. As long as it contains the static webmethod, you're good to go!

Comment: how do i do this in vb.net? I'm not using MVC.

Comment: It's not MVC, just C# and WebForms :o) You only need to write the SayHello-method in VB. The Javascript-code stays the same ;o)

Comment: I get a message of "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement."

Comment: I actually never really programmed in VB.NET. I don't have Visual Studio right now to check it; will update you within an hour!

Comment: @jack Just tried the code and compiles fine. Are you sure you copied all the code (including the underscore)?

Comment: yes, now i'm able to run my project but I'm not able to hit the code behind function. I dont know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-forms---calling-web-service-page-methods-using-jquery